# Why auto property be seen in the Unity inspector but with condition it can

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, serialization, collections

When I create this class and open a List with this custom class, the one with FullName can be seen in the inspector, but the one with Age cant be. I wonder why? Since the Age is public property, it should be seen as it is public get and set.

```
[Serializable]
        public class YoungPerson
        {
            public string FullName;
            public string fullname
            {
                get { return FullName;}
                set { FullName = value; }
            }
            public int Age { get; set; }
    
            public YoungPerson(string fullName, int age)
            {
                this.FullName = fullName;
                this.Age = age;
            }
        }
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Because what you see in the Inspector is **not** the [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

```
public string fullname { ... }
```

but rather the serialized [**field**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

```
public string FullName;
```

You can already see that on the naming - `fullname` would be displayed as `Fullname` not as `Full Name` as per [`ObjectNames.NicifyVariableName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ObjectNames.NicifyVariableName.html) ;)

Unity's Serializer doesn't serialize properties by default - see [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) -> `Serialization of properties`.

---

You can either add a backing field implementation like you also did for the name e.g.

```
// In that case I would always rather go for private
// anything else is just confusing / why would you use the property 
// when you can anyway read/write the field directly
[SerializeField] private int age;

public int Age
{
    get => age;
    set => age = value;
}
```

or - as already mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73445252/7111561) - force serialize the property via (unfortunately undocumented for whatever reason)

```
[field: SerializeField]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

as also mentioned by the other answer this has some hickups (see e.g. [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-7-3-field-serializefield-support.573988/page-2)) though

Answer (score 0):

Unity Editor dont show property in Inspector, you see on `public string FullName` field but not `public string fullName` property. Make public field for Age to see this in inspector

Comment: so even if the property is public get and set, the inspector won't be able to see it due to it being a property? if that's true is there any way to work around it?

Comment: Yes inspector never shows the property, as i talk you can create a field as for fullName

Answer (score 0):

Unity can't serialize properties, it's mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).

Comment: yes you can .. it is just not documented ;) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73445252/7111561) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73446127/7111561)

Comment: Unity docs....ughh

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Unity does not officially support serializing properties.
But it *is* possible.

This should work just fine:

```
[field: SerializeField] public string FullName { get; set; }
```

However, it still has some quirks, as mentioned [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-7-3-field-serializefield-support.573988/page-2). You'll have to judge for yourself whether it's a good idea to use it.