# Can't Assign Game Object from inspector on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm working on a unity project and have added the **Assembly definition** to my project to keep things more organized. But now that I have added the Assembly Definition I can't assign any object at all from the inspector (no matter if it's a public or serialized field)

### I have tried:

- To make the fields serialized
- Changed the file namespace

  1. Removed the namespace
  2. Changed that to the Root directory
- I also tried moving the file to another directory (directly under assets)

I also have added the Root namespaces at project settings>>editor.

And all the **Assembly definitions** have the same **Root namespaces**

**Any suggestion would mean a lot to me, Thanks!**

**Inspector in normal state**

[image]

### Here is the inspector under Debug

[image]

### The scripts are all under the Scripts folder

[image]

here is my class.

```
    using IndritVaka.Assets.Script.Core;
    using IndritVaka.Assets.Script.Model;
    using TMPro;
    using UnityEngine;
    namespace IndritVaka.Assets.Script.IO
    {
        public class OutputManager: MonoBehaviour
        {
            public TextMeshProUGUI Date { get; set; }
            public TextMeshProUGUI Imsak { get; set; }
            public TextMeshProUGUI Fajr { get; set; }
            public TextMeshProUGUI Sunrise { get; set; }
            public TextMeshProUGUI Dhuhr { get; set; }
            public TextMeshProUGUI Asr { get; set; }
            public TextMeshProUGUI Sunset { get; set; }
            public TextMeshProUGUI Isha { get; set; }
    
            private void Awake()
            {
                TimingUtility.UPDATE_TIMINGS_UI += UpdateUi;
            }
    
            private void UpdateUi(Timings timings)
            {
                Date.text = timings.Date?.ToShortDateString();
                Imsak.text = timings.Imsak?.ToShortTimeString();
                Fajr.text = timings.Fajr?.ToShortTimeString();
                Sunrise.text = timings.Sunrise?.ToShortTimeString();
                Dhuhr.text = timings.Dhuhr?.ToShortTimeString();
                Asr.text = timings.Asr?.ToShortTimeString();
                Sunset.text = timings.Sunset?.ToShortTimeString();
                Isha.text = timings.Isha?.ToShortTimeString();
            }
            private void OnDestroy()
            {
                TimingUtility.UPDATE_TIMINGS_UI -= UpdateUi;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with assembly language.  Please take more care when adding tags.

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem was at set and set

Comment: You cannot serialize properties. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73440181/why-auto-property-be-seen-in-the-unity-inspector-but-with-condition-it-can/73444499?noredirect=1#comment129702845_73444499).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use auto properties and still want to expose them in the inspector, you can add the `SerializeFieldAttribute`, like you always would, but add a `field:` in front of it. This will add the attribute to the auto-generated backing field, resulting in it being serialized like it would if you wrote a full property.

```
[field: SerializeField]
public GameObject StuffToAssign { get; }
```

Comment: Thanks :)!  that works.
I also would like to know, is a good practice, does that comes with any downside?

Comment: Using properties over fields is always good practice, as fields should never be `public`. Ideally, you want to serialize the field with an attribute and make it available to other classes if there is a grain from it. In your case, I wouldn't use `public` at all, since only the class itself cares for the reference. A simple private field would be enough then. I haven't used the field-target for attributes that much, but so far I can see no downsides when using it with `SerializeField`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't have to do at all with assembly.
The problem was  at get and set
Removing them fixed the problem.

```
public TextMeshProUGUI Date { get; set; }
```

to

```
public TextMeshProUGUI Date;
```